# PHP button click - value / id to pass over

Tags: php, xml

Hey I'm currently having a problem with trying to make my input button have a value of the id / server that I need and it showing a different value this is how my code currently looks I know the HTML and forms are invalid I will be refactoring it however I'm trying to get a server identifier and a id identifier to cross to another page

```
<?php
$propertyType = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('PropertyType');
$rent = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('rates');
$rooms = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('rooms');
//$server = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('server');
$propertyServer = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('Property');
$propertyID = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('Property');
$imageURL = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('url');
$imageAlt = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('altText');
$server = $propertyID->item($i)->getAttribute('server');
echo '<form action="level5Details.php" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">';
echo '<table><th>Type:</th><th>Rent:</th><th>Rooms:</th><th>Server</th>';
$records = $xmlDom1->documentElement->childNodes;
for ($i = 0; $i < $records->length; $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$propertyType->item($i)->nodeValue."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rent->item($i)->nodeValue."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rooms->item($i)->nodeValue."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$propertyServer->item($i)->getAttribute('Server')."</td>"; 
    echo '<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageURL->item($i)->nodeValue.'" alt="'.$imageAlt->item($i)->nodeValue.'"></img></td>';
?> 
    <td>
        <button class="submit" type="submit" value="<?php echo $propertyID->item($i)->getAttribute('pid');  ?>" name="submit22">something </button>
    </td>
 </tr>
<?php 
} 
?>
</form>
```

Comment: why you creating form tag inside the loop ?

Comment: First of all, you need to stop creating invalid HTML - `form` can not be a child of `table`, you either need to put the table inside the form, or the form within a single table cell.

Comment: What the variable '$propertyType' contains ?

Comment: **Guys/Gals** I think OP is trying to create multiple forms each with a submit button containing the KEY he wants to use in the PHP script

Comment: I have made the changes made from your feedback< Any feedback is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to generate lots of form each with just a button then you need to put the form in a table cell like this

It might also be useful to place the data items you want to pass in hidden fields rather than try and put 2 data items in the button value

```
<?php
$propertyType = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('PropertyType');
$rent = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('rates');
$rooms = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('rooms');
//$server = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('server');
$propertyServer = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('Property');
$propertyID = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('Property');
$imageURL = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('url');
$imageAlt = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('altText');
$server = $propertyID->item($i)->getAttribute('server');
echo '<table><th>Type:</th><th>Rent:</th><th>Rooms:</th><th>Server</th>';
$records = $xmlDom1->documentElement->childNodes;
for ($i = 0; $i < $records->length; $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$propertyType->item($i)->nodeValue."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rent->item($i)->nodeValue."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rooms->item($i)->nodeValue."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$propertyServer->item($i)->getAttribute('Server')."</td>"; 
    echo '<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageURL->item($i)->nodeValue.'" alt="'.$imageAlt->item($i)->nodeValue.'"></img></td>';

    $pid = $propertyID->item($i)->getAttribute('pid'); 
?> 
    <td>
        <form action="level5Details.php" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $pid;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="server" value="<?php echo $server;?>">
            <button class="submit" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit22">something</button>
        </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

If you just want the button to carry all the data and have only one form you will have to package the 2 data items into one string and sent it as the value of the button

```
<?php
$propertyType = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('PropertyType');
$rent = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('rates');
$rooms = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('rooms');
//$server = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('server');
$propertyServer = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('Property');
$propertyID = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('Property');
$imageURL = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('url');
$imageAlt = $xmlDom1->getElementsByTagName('altText');
$server = $propertyID->item($i)->getAttribute('server');

echo '<form action="level5Details.php" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">';

echo '<table><th>Type:</th><th>Rent:</th><th>Rooms:</th><th>Server</th>';
$records = $xmlDom1->documentElement->childNodes;

for ($i = 0; $i < $records->length; $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$propertyType->item($i)->nodeValue."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rent->item($i)->nodeValue."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rooms->item($i)->nodeValue."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$propertyServer->item($i)->getAttribute('Server')."</td>"; 
    echo '<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageURL->item($i)->nodeValue.'" alt="'.$imageAlt->item($i)->nodeValue.'"></img></td>';

    $dataPackage = $propertyID->item($i)->getAttribute('pid') . ':' . $server; 
?> 
    <td>
        <button class="submit" type="submit" value="<?php echo $dataPackage;?>" name="submit22">something</button>

    </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
} 
</table>
</form>
?>
```

Now in the receiving form unpack the data for use

```
<?php
// usual checks for things existing
list($pid, $server) = explode(':', $_GET['submit22'];
```

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure which is better programmatically to have many forms or just one because they're all referring to the same place, this worked very well actually thank you very much I was trying to pass the id and server on each button click so button 1 held value 1 and the server it belonged to

Comment: From your code, `server` stays the same all through the loop, but `pid` changes each time through the loop. So surely you need more than one button?

Comment: Well the button is meant to carry the information id and server over to another page which is then used for the rest of that webpage

Comment: Ok, I had another try at getting to what you wanted